# Lock during ApplyEdits

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase

Have a JavaScript application trying to push data to a FeatureServer on ArcGIS Server 10.1.

I get this error occasionally:
{Error code '400': 'Unable to complete operation.'
Lock request conflicts with an established lock [dbo.DEFAULT]}

Comment: It sounds like you have a locking problem with multiple users, is this the case? Do you have multiple editors - via JavaScript, tools (may not be ESRI) and ArcMap?

Comment: There is a Geodatabase Replica setup. Processing is done on the offline geodatabase using ArcMap. Can logs tell me what is locking it?

Comment: And yes there are several people logging in the JavaScript application to edit their set of features.

Comment: Which part uses the replica? A file or personal geodatabase replica, despite originating from SDE, does not have multiuser capability; you can look with multiple viewers but as soon as one process start editing you start locking. By having a replica you have introduced a version in SDE, though the error is with default, which may be SDE or might be file/personal geodatabase.

Comment: The applyEdits is posting to a FeatureClass in SDE, not File/Personal gdb.

Comment: Is it possible that this occurs when two users try to save at the same time? I know that ArcMap has a save edits warning, which can be turned off, when another user saves during your edit session. Does javascript have a try..catch? if so catch the exception and try again in 10 seconds or so.

Comment: Tried repeatedly like 10 times, didn't work. Worked when I tried it an hour later.

Comment: Locks are created for numerous reasons: adding fields, creating feature classes, compressing and backing up etc. If you can't find any good reason why a lock exists it's time to contact ESRI support.